# Old connectionId when new web socket connection triggered by DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, websocket, amazon-dynamodb, event-handling, amazon-cloudwatch

I see in CloudWatch that only sporadically the `connectionId` of new web socket connections are successfully conveyed by an event, triggered by a new and correct DynamoDB entry...

What I do:

- **Connect.** From a localhost front-end, I connect to a web socket `wss://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production`. A `Connect` lambda function stores the `connectionId` each time successfully in a DynamoDB table. This `connectiondId` varies per connection.
- **Trigger.** When a new DynamoDB entry is created, an event is sent by a trigger to a `Broadcast` lambda function. In its current form this `Broadcast` function (see below) only prints the `connectionId` which is conveyed in the event (the result is printed in CloudWatch). Here is the problem: This `connectionId` keeps on being the same, while it should change per new connection... Like there is lazy event cache that should be cleared?
- **Disconnect.** When at the front-end the web socket connection is ended, a `Disconnect` lambda function removes the `connectionId` successfully from the DynamoDB table. I thought: This helps to prevent mixing up `connectionIds`, but not.

Question: How is it possible the same `connectionId` is repeatedly printed for different web socket connections? (see attached images) The DynamoDB tables work as expected, and once triggered should convey the correct table entry/value in the event, isn't it?

Side question: Why are some log streams in Cloud Watch clustered and others separate?

**Broadcast lambda python code**

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('apigatewaymanagementapi', endpoint_url="https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # get connectionId from DynamoDB
    print(event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['Keys']['connectionid']['S'])
```

**CloudWatch logs for different web socket connections**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by filtering INSERT events sent to the `Broadcast` script. Since also MODIFY and REMOVE events are sent to the script by DynamoDB, once listed as a trigger, and are therefore logged in CloudWatch.

Below code does the job in the `Broadcast` script

```
# only look at INSERT dynamodb events and collect connectionId
if record.get('eventName') in ('INSERT'):
    id = record['dynamodb']['Keys']['connectionid']['S']
    print("connectionId: ", id)
else:
    pass
```